# SQL order by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select data from my SQL table which look like this:

```
| Title | Date      | Active |
| A     | 2022-02-01| 1|
| B     | 2022-01-01| 1|
| C     | 2022-04-01| 1|
| A     | 2021-02-01| 0|
| B     | 2021-03-01| 0|
| C     | 2020-04-01| 0|
```

So result should look like this:

```
| Title | Date      | Active |
| B     | 2022-01-01| 1|
| B     | 2021-03-01| 0|
| A     | 2022-02-01| 1|
| A     | 2021-02-01| 0|
| C     | 2022-04-01| 1|
| C     | 2020-04-01| 0|
```

Order first by date and group by title, and active first. GROUp BY date, title, active gives me order by date only.

Comment: Can you check this  : select * from yourTable group by title, `date` desc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to order by the minimum date per title group ascending, followed by the `Active` column descending.  We can use:

```sql
SELECT Title, Date, Active
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Title), Active DESC;
```

Comment: What if I have another row - 'D', with date 2021-01-01 and active - 1, so it's should be on top, but it's below rows which have more than one repeated title ? Is it real to do something with it ?

Comment: Use: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Title = 'D'  AND Date = '2021-01-01' AND Active = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Title), Active DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is to track the chaning of active/inactive by date on these objects - Try:

```
ORDER BY TITLE ASC, DATE DESC
```

Partition would also work but I don't think it's necessary for this specific example.

Comment: I want to order by date first, your version will put title 'A' on the top, not 'B'